# Не корректно работает функция gets()

Tags: c, строки, ввод

Не корректно работают функции gets()
(Мне кажется это что-то банальное но все же) 
P.S. Это хедер в котором я пишу функцию

```
    struct device
{
    char name[20];
    struct dcost Dcost;
    struct velichina Velichina;   
    struct costumer Customer;
};
void sfilling(struct device *pdev)
{setlocale(LC_ALL,"rus");
 printf("Введите название устройства ");
 scanf("%s",pdev->name);

 printf("Введите стоимость ");
 scanf("%f",&pdev->Dcost.cost);

 printf("Введите верхнюю границу ");
 scanf("%f",&pdev->Velichina.v_granica);

 printf("Введите нижнюю границу ");
 scanf("%f",&pdev->Velichina.n_granica);

 printf("Введите погрешность ");
 scanf("%f",&pdev->Velichina.pogreshnost);

 printf("Введите ФИО заказчика");
 gets(pdev->Customer.fullname);

 printf("Введите адресс доставки заказа");
 gets(pdev->Customer.address);

 printf("Введите кол-во устройств закупаемых заказчиком");
 scanf("%d",&pdev->Customer.d_num);


}
```

[image: Вот что получаеться когда доходим до ФИО]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да как обычно - считали число, а строку до конца не сбросили...

Добавьте после `scanf("%f",...` и перед `gets` что-то вроде

```
while(getchar()!='\n');
```

Comment: а ещё не хватает дежурного предупреждения (лучше всего жирного красного и мигающего) «**никогда не пользуйся gets ()**».